# Trazer dados como o mural do facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, post

estou implementando uma funcionalidade de trazer dados como o mural de post's do facebook, aparentemente não é nada muito difícil, porém, tenho uma dúvida e gostaria de saber se alguém tem uma solução ou sugestão para esse meu problema.

O código

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    pesquisar("","");
  }
});
```

No código acima, eu possuo uma função que faz uma execução ajax para retornar determinados dados, porém, eu gostaria de atualizar a página com novos dados e não repetindo eles que é o que acontece comigo no momento. Eu testei a função find('div').remove() para ter uma suposta "atualização" de dados, porém, isso é horrível, o usuário perde a referência de onde o scroll está e acaba voltando pro início. Alguém teria uma sugestão melhor para adicionar a informação sem repetir o conteúdo já adicionado?

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar a função AppendTo('#elemento') ou isertAfter("#elemento"), ambas vão manter o conteúdo atual e adicionar o novo conteudo ao final do elemento passado como parâmetro.

Ficaria assim:

```
//insere os dados dentro do container, no final.
$(dadosVindosDoAjax).appendTo("#containerDePosts");
```

ou:

```
//este insere os dados depois da ultima postagem
$(dadosVindosDoAjax).insertAfter($("#containerDePosts").find("#postagens").last());
```